# Jech Axiom of Choice Theorem 8.12

Tags: proof-explanation, set-theory

Theorem 8.12 of Jech's Axiom of Choice (page 130) states that for any regular cardinal $\kappa$, there is a permutation model where Dependent Choice fails and AC$_\lambda$ holds for every $\lambda < \kappa$. My question is about the construction of the permutation model.

Start with a set $A$ of atoms of size $\kappa$ and identify each atom with a finite sequence of ordinals less than $\kappa$. We then order these sequences (i.e., atoms) by inclusion and consider the group of all automorphisms. To produce the permutation, we also need an ideal of subsets of $A$.

Jech defines the ideal $I$ as follows. For any $E \subseteq A$, $E \in I$ iff $|E| < \kappa$ and $E$ is upward-closed (i.e., if $t \in E$ and $s \subseteq t$, then $s \in E$) with no infinite branch.

My question is that I did not see why $I$ so defined is an ideal: how do we know that if $F \subseteq E$ and $E \in I$, then $F \in I$? F may not be upward-closed after all. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we define an ideal or a filter, it is often easier to talk about a generating family, or a basis, rather than the actual ideal or filter.

You are right, of course, that not every subset of a tree is a tree itself. But by making a set larger, we only make the stabilizer smaller. So if we know that a set of atoms is contained in a well founded tree, we may as well assume it is one.

As long as the basis generates a normal ideal/filter of groups, there is no problem.